# Turn Based Game player receives its own data without opponent calling takeTurn

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have been implementing my own turn based board game. Whole game is based on PlayGameService's [SkeletonTbmp example](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/SkeletonTbmp/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/tbmpskeleton) with some modifications.

My problem is that a player sometimes receives its own data that it sent to the opponent using `takeTurn()`. I have checked many times that `getNextParticipantId()` returns the right id. For example my emulator persists a move data and sends it correctly to my actual Android phone and my phone unpersists as implemented in the example. Then some seconds later my emulator receives this same data without actual device persisting it and calling `takeTurn()`. This also happens sometimes on game start on the first turn, emulator receives the first "dummy" turn data without actual device sending anything yet. It does not happen every single turn, just occasionally.

Could this be something with my Google Play Console settings or does these turns buffer some how and then they are released at some point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that i just forgot to always remove the old games from the "check games"-UI, thats why it sends the same data after a while, when i am already attending to a new game with same opponent.

Answer (score 2):

As you have not giving any codes i cannot pinpoint the problem. But just for the explanation, as long as the match is going, match will contain data, whether its your turn or not. To pinpoint the exact place this is happening, put checks at the execution of updatematch() as it must be firing without actual need. (on login, reconnect, initiate, connectionhint etc). Can't be sure about your code but alternate approach to bypass the bug, you can actually put check on turncounter in addition of MATCH_TURN_STATUS_MY_TURN otherwise pass the null turn. Hope it helps as further i cant help without your code.